# CDF of the squared radius

Tags: probability

Pick a point uniformly at random from the unit circle -

$(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leqslant 1$

Let $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$ be the distance from the origin.

What is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $R^2$?

Reasoning geometrically, it's easy to convince myself that the CDF of $R$ is determined by a ratio of circles.  We simply divide area of the circle with radius $R = r$ by the area of the unit circle.

$$F_R(r) = P(R \leqslant r) = \frac{\pi r^2}{\pi * 1^2} = r^2 $$

Is there a similar approach to finding the CDF of $R^2$ or is it necessary to resort to calculus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $F_R(r)= r^2\cdot \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant r\leqslant 1}$ exactly for the reason you gave.

Then no calculus is required to reason that: $F_{R^2}(\rho) ~{= \mathsf P(R^2\leqslant \rho) \\ = \mathsf P(-\surd \rho\leqslant R\leqslant\surd \rho) \\= F_R(\surd \rho)\require{cancel}\cancelto 0{ -F_R(-\surd\rho)} \\ = {\rho} \cdot \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant \rho\leqslant 1} }$